# vbscrip error on set OpenTextFile()

Tags: text-files

This code reads all files (.txt) in the folder where the script is placed and echo's the 6the line of each txt file.

I get an error here: `Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objFSO.name, 1)` in the following code:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Wscript.Echo Wscript.ScriptFullName
Wscript.Echo left(Wscript.ScriptFullName, InStrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, "\"))

sFolder = left(Wscript.ScriptFullName, InStrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, "\"))

For Each objFSO In objFSO.GetFolder(sFolder).Files

    Wscript.Echo objFSO.name

    if objFSO.name <> Wscript.ScriptName then

    Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objFSO.name, 1)
        For i = 1 to 5
            objTextFile555.ReadLine
        Next
    end if

strLine = objTextFile555.ReadLine
Wscript.Echo strLine
objTextFile.Close

Next
```

Comment: please edit the question -  add correct tag to the question to indicate the language, and also please show exactly what the error message says (in a code block)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem -> `Set FileRead = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objTextFile.name, 1)`

Full code:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

sFolder = left(Wscript.ScriptFullName, InStrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, "\"))

For Each objTextFile in objFSO.GetFolder(sFolder).Files

    msgbox (objTextFile.name)

    if objTextFile.name <> Wscript.ScriptName then

        Set FileRead = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objTextFile.name, 1)
        For i = 1 to 5
            FileRead.ReadLine
        Next
            Wscript.Echo FileRead.ReadLine
        End If  
Next
```